# Disabling styles in HTML tags

Tags: php, html

How do I disable styles in HTML tags so that

```
"<b style="color:red;">"
```

Changes to

```
"<b>"
```

Comment: I couldn't as I was on my mobile phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the power of regular expressions...

```
$input = '<span style="color:red;">Example</span>';
$html = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) style=".*?"/i', '$1', $input);

echo $html;
```

This outputs `<span>Example</span>`.

Comment: If the style is a bit tricky (on multiple lines, or containing quotes, for instance), it won't work as expected

Comment: This will only work on a single tag. Fro many tags you should form the expression like `style="[^"]*"`

Comment: @tmuguet it won't work with a line break, but will handle `<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;background-image:url(\'img.jpg\';">Example</span>`, for example.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp I have tested my expression with a couple of tags: `'<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;background-image:url(\'img.jpg\';">Example</span><p style="color:red;">Blah</p>'`

Comment: @SteveFenton I think it won't work with `<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;background-image:url(\"img.jpg\";">Example</sp‌​an>`

Comment: @tmuguet try it - even though I've made a typo there, it works with the typo and it works without the typo. I have actually run this to test it.

Answer (score 1):

The safest way to do so it to use a DOM parser (for example http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), traverse all the document to find `style` attributes and remove them.

Comment: +1 I don't really see why this was downvoted. The DOM is simply the way to go...

Comment: @bažmegakapa -1 because it's more of a comment than an answer. It's easier to post a two-liner than actually code the cumbersome DOM traversal and manipulation.

Comment: @mario The way I see it, if you think it is not an answer (which I, hm, might even agree with), there is a flag button. The downvote button has "This answer is not useful.", while it clearly is useful.

Comment: @bažmegakapa There's an actual DOM answer in the linked duplicate. And in comparison to that, this one is objectively less enlightening. Specifically what voting is for, not moderator intervention.

Comment: @mario That is true, and I voted to close. This answer is still technically right, even though too short, but if someone sees a downvote on this one, and no downvote on the other regex answer, he might as well think regex is the best solution - which is not.

Comment: @bažmegakapa Couldn't upvote the regex answer myself, because that's an exact copy from the one in the duplicate. Even though I disagree with the Stackoverflow Use-DOM-for-everything meme. The question is arguably stupid, since we don't know the use case (random HTML vs. template output), so there's no saying if regex or DOM is more appropriate. (Firing up libxml2 for hundreds of short HTML snippets is, in fact, dumb IMO).

Comment: @mario +1 on that comment, but I do not see these very important and clever points you make in the regex answers, unfortunately. If one is ignorant, or does not know what he does, better use DOM...

Comment: @mario I see your point about down-voting, my bad. About DOM vs Regex, I totally agree: that's why I didn't say DOM is the best way or the more appropriate.